# Как избавиться от Drag&Drop элементов на странице?

Tags: html, javascript, css

FireFox 7.0.1. HTML:

```
<body>
      <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: grey"></div>      
</body>
```

А теперь внимание: пытаемся перетащить квадратик... Ничего не получилось. Теперь сразу перетаскиваем этот квадратик еще раз... и у меня появляется системный Drag&Drop.
Он мне очень мешает! Как от него избавиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div style="width: 200px; height: 30px; background-color: grey" oncontextmenu="return false" ondragstart="return false"></div>
```

Всем спасибо - все свободны